# Strategy to route to pages in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, methods, routes, controller

i was wondering whats the best way to route to pages in codeigniter?  Say for example user wants to route to the index page, but should i create a method in a controller that just fo rthat page, or what is better way?

Comment: basically the way i do it now is by creating a method for every page.  But is there a better strategy?

Comment: You mean static pages where the content isn't dynamic?

Comment: yes exactly, just pages where there is no security or data from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to create separate methods or controllers. Here's how I do it:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    function _remap($method)
    {
        is_file(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$method.'.php') OR show_404();
        $this->load->view("pages/$method");
    }

}
```

So the url `http://example.com/pages/about` would load the view file `application/views/pages/about.php`. If the file doesn't exist, it shows a 404.

You don't need any special routing to do this, but you can do something like this if you wanted the URL to be `http://example.com/about` instead:

```
// Route the "about" page
$route['about'] = "pages/$1";

// Route ALL requests to the static page handler
$route['(:any)'] = "pages/$1";
```

Comment: ya this is what i was thinking...thanks, so i was on the right track.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty straight forward, the details like routing and which class name to use, where the view files are, etc. just depend on your project.

Comment: a lot simplier than a case statement and is prettier code + 1 and is easier explained here than the CI docs/.

Comment: ya the code docs seriously need to follow the java doc library style, with examples offcourse.  But they need to further elaborate on the concepts thats for sure.

Comment: Could you not read internal files with this!??!!? what if $method is ../../config/config.php?!?

Comment: @Kush: It's safe, `$method` is always the first argument and the slashes and dots are stripped. Try it!

Comment: How can I make it more elegant, like say, `mysite.com/about`, instead of `mysite.com/pages/about` ? Should I put the `_remap()` method inside my main controller? Perhaps an `is_file()` statement for a variety of routes?

Comment: @ronnieaka Use routing: `$route['about'] = 'pages/about';` IF your *entire* sites uses the generic page controller then I guess you could use `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/$1';`

Answer (score 1):

Routing can be done using the `application/config/routes.php` file. You can define custom routes redirecting to the index page there. There is absolutly no need to create methods for every page.

A more detailed explanation can be found here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

EDIT:
Didn't realy got what you meant, but here is the solution I use:

```
class Static_pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function show_page($page = 'index')
    {
        if ( ! file_exists('application/views/static_pages/'.$page.'.php'))
            show_404();

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('static_pages/'.$page);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

}
```

I make 1 controller in `application/controllers` for the static pages with 1 method in it that I use to load in the static pages.

Then I add this line to `application/config/routes.php`:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'static_pages/show_page/$1';
//you can also change the default_controller to show this static page controller
$route['default_controller'] = 'static_pages/show_page';
```

Comment: well there are times where some pages in the website are just informational like the abouts page for instance...so for these instances whats the best way to route to that page?

Comment: umm with that approach all your pages/requests will be called by the static page controller...

Comment: I use routes for all my pages, this is my last line.

Comment: That was helpful to me, and I know it was a typo, but for the newcomers to PHP, there should be only one equals sign in the default argument value in the function declaration. It should read: public function show_page($page = 'index')

Answer (score 0):

In the config file located at `/application/config/routes.php`

Comment: yes i know..but i wanted to know best routing strategy for routing to pages that are not data sensitive or static pages.

Comment: why are you using codeigniter to server up static pages? If you _really_ need to server static pages that dont need a database access you should be using something else. Perhaps, you should use a subdomain with just that content? or make a new folder in the same directory as your application folder and allow it to be accessed in your .htaccess

Comment: well there are times where some pages in the website are just informational like the abouts page for instance...so for these instances whats the best way to route to that page?

Comment: hmm how bout i create a method in a controller that handles the pages?

Comment: .what about a method with a simple case statement? to load view files ?