# codeigniter routing don't work

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I am trying to change the url of my website from

```
www.somedomain.com/contact/contactDetails/55
```

to

```
www.somedomain.com/contactme
```

In the above URL, contact is the controller name, contactDetails is the function and the 55 is parameter passed to the function.

in the route, I have done the following:

```
$route['contactme'] = 'contact/contactDetails/55';
```

but after uploading the file on the server, the URL remains the same.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to visit `www.example.com/contactme` ?

Comment: What did you mean `url` remains the same ? try `www.somedomain.com/contactme`.

Answer (score 0):

> Here are a few routing examples:
>
> $route['journals'] = "blogs";
> A URL containing the word "journals" in the first segment will be remapped to the "blogs" class.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

You should do something like

```
$route['contact/contactDetails/55'] = 'contactme'; //you are trying to remap the url contact/contactDetails/35 to contactme class
```

You can also look at [Strategy to route to pages in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636380/strategy-to-route-to-pages-in-codeigniter)